# fullCalendar viewRender with ajax in infinite loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am trying to set up a calendar in which the businessHours can vary throughout the year.  For example, an ice cream store that is open from 12:00-10:00 P.M. from May 30th - October 1st every year.  I have figured out how to pull the business hours from the server via an ajax call; but I want to make sure they update if the user moves between views in which the businessHours change.  Using the example of the ice cream store again, if the user starts on the week before May 30th and then navigates to the week of May 30th, the businessHours should change.

To do this, I'm using jquery's $.post within the function for viewRender (as shown below)

```
viewRender: function(view, element){
               $.post("calendar_constraint_ajax.php", {start:    view.start.format(), end: view.end.format()}, function(json_bh) {
                if(json_bh != 'error')
                {
                    var bh = JSON.parse(json_bh);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', {businessHours: bh, selectConstraint: "businessHours"});
                }
            });
        }
```

I get the change in business hours that I expect.  But something repeatedly calls the server: [view of Network in Chrome Developer Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKJ99.png)

When I don't include the AJAX call, this only seems to run once, but with the $.post, it seems to be stuck in an infinite loop.

I have two questions:
1.) Why does it keep calling the server?
2.) Is there a better way to update the businessHours property when the date range changes?  (I'm still pretty new to fullCalendar.)

Comment: is it possible that setting the businessHours option causes the view to be rendered again (because it has to physically re-draw the highlighting on the screen), causing the viewRender callback to be triggered again, which causes the businessHours option to be set, which causes the viewRender to be triggered...etc? That would be my guess, but possibly you can check the source code to see what happens when you set that option.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like unsolved issue
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3519

so alternately, I solved this dirty.

```
viewRender: () => {
    if(!this.initComplte) {
        this.renderCalendarEvents();
        this.initComplte = true;
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did something similar by externalizing my view and nav buttons.  I'm going to try posting the code below.

Answer (score 0):

viewRender is firing multiple times because the event fires in several situations.

Here is the info regarding viewRender:

> Callback will get triggered when the user changes the view, or when
>   any of the date navigation methods are called.

So most likely you are calling it in another function you have - without realizing it.

You could try updating the hours using the eventAfterAllEvents to prevent repeated calls:

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/

Comment: I replaced "viewRender" in the code above with  "eventAfterAllRender", and got the same result (infinite loop of ajax calls).  Thank you for giving me something else to ponder, though.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up building my own buttons for prev, next, and the views that I'm allowing so that I can do other stuff before it renders.  See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/prev/ for an example in the documentation that I started with.  I implemented it as:

```
$('#prev').click(function(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('prev');
        getBusinessHours($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start.format(), $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').end.format());
    });
```

with getBusinessHours defined as:

```
function getBusinessHours(start_dt, end_dt)
{
    $.post("calendar_constraint_ajax.php", {start: start_dt, end: end_dt, rid: '<?=utilities::encode($rid);?>'}, function(json_bh) {
        if(json_bh != 'error')
        {
            var bh = JSON.parse(json_bh);
            //console.log(bh);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', {businessHours: bh, selectConstraint: "businessHours"});
        }
    });
}
```

to pull in the business hours for a given date range from the server.

Thank you to everyone who responded this for your comments/answers.  It helped me work out a solution for this.